# SQL Server how to use a single SELECT query in this case?

Tags: sql-server

I am performing a SELECT on two tables, the selection is conditional on the tables' primary ID, so I expect at most 1 result from each query. I'd like to combine the queries into a single SELECT statement. I thought I should do this using a RIGHT (or maybe a LEFT) OUTER JOIN, but this isn't working for me. Any suggestions?

```
  Table A             Table B
    ---------          ----------
    ID (pk) | AAttr    ID (pk) | BAttr

    SELECT AAttr, BAttr 
    FROM A 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN B
      ON B.ID = 1
    WHERE A.ID = 1
```

*Edited to include sample cases

For example, if the tables contained the first set of data and querying for an ID of `1`, I'd expect:

```
[null, 'b']
```

For the second set of data and querying for an ID of `1`, I'd expect:

```
['a', null]
```

And for the third set of data and querying for an ID of `1`, I'd expect:

```
['a', 'b']


Table A   Table B 
--------  --------
2 | a     1 | b
3 | c     4 | d

Table A   Table B 
--------  --------
1 | a     2 | b
3 | c     4 | d

Table A   Table B 
--------  --------
1 | a     1 | b
3 | c     4 | d
```

Comment: Please include sample data from both tables and the results you'd like to obtain from that sample data.

Comment: Ok, I edited in sample data and expected results.

Comment: You want a `FULL JOIN` (not `RIGHT`, not `LEFT`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you join to tables, you need to relate them to each other via a common column. In this case, the ID.

```
SELECT a.AAttr, b.BAttr
    FROM a
        LEFT JOIN b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
    WHERE a.ID = 1;
```

Comment: the IDs in each table are unrelated. I was hoping to just combine two unrelated select statements.

Answer (score 1):

if IDs in each table are unrelated and you want to combine two unrelated select statements, try this

```
select
    (SELECT top 1 AAttr FROM A where ID = 1) as AAttr, 
    (SELECT top 1 BAttr FROM B where ID = 1) as BAttr
```